Convergence of a net and its associated filter
I am reading "Topology: An Introduction" by Waldmann and I am trying to prove the result (iv) in Proposition 4.2.6:


A net converges to $p$ $\iff$ its associated filter converges to $p$.

I understood that if a net converges to $p$, then its associated filter converges to $p$ but I am having problem with the converse.
The book suggests using the following results:



Proposition 4.1.12: A net $S_n$ converges to $p$ $\iff$ every subnet of $S_n$ converges to $p$.
A filter converges to $p$ $\iff$ its associated net converges to $p$.

(I apologize for using the picture of the book.)
It may be trivial but I don't know how to fit them all together.
Can somebody help me?

Are you only having a problem with (iv)?

Yes: I haven't written the other results of Proposition 4.2.6, but the (iv) which is the one that I've posted here is the only one I am having trouble with. (The other three I understood). Whereas I have already proved the four results of Proposition 4.2.3 but I don't know how to use them properly to show the fact that if a filter associated to a net converges to $p$, then the net converges to $p$. I hope I was clear. :)

Hint: for any open neighborhood $U$ of $p$, that neighborhood will be in the corresponding filter by assumption, so there exists $i \in I$ such that $A_i \subseteq U$.

Suppose that $\langle p_i\rangle_{i\in J}$ is a net over $M,$ that $\mathfrak{F}$ is the filter associated to the net, and that $p\in M$ such that $\mathfrak{F}$ converges to $p.$
Take any $U\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $p\in U.$ By definition of convergence of a filter, every neighborhood of $p$ is an element of $\mathfrak{F},$ and in particular, $U\in\mathfrak{F}.$ Consider the filter basis $\mathfrak{B}=\{A_j:j\in J\}.$ By definition of filter basis, since $U\in\mathfrak{F},$ then $U$ is a superset of some element $\mathfrak{B},$ meaning that there is some $j\in J$ such that $A_j\subseteq U.$
Do you see how to take it from there, given that $U$ is an arbitrary neighborhood of the point $p$?

Yes. thank you!
